# Automatic parameter forwarding on overloaded methods with variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, forward

I have a class **A** with multiple overloads of a method **open** (all with variadic templates):

```
class A {
   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int, Args...);
   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int, string, Args...);
   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int, string, char, Args...); 
}
```

Then I have a class **B**, which has a member **A**, and must support all the overloads for this open function

```
class B {
   A a;

   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int i, Args... args) {
       // do stuff
       return a.open(i, args...);
   }

   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int i, string s, Args... args) {
       // do the same stuff
       return a.open(i, s, args...);
   }

   template<typename... Args>
   bool open(int i, string s, char c, Args... args) {
       // do the same stuff
       return a.open(i, s, c, args...);
   } 
}
```

But I would like to avoid creating a "copy" of every overload on class B, given they take the same parameters as A. I would like to know if it is possible to make a generic **open** method at B that forwards its arguments, and the complier can automatically calls the correct overload when calling **b.open()**, like so:

```
    template<typename... Args>
    bool open(Args&& ... args) {
       // do stuff
        return a.open(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

And then maybe create a template specialization for each overload if needed. (would still be much better than a full method for each overload).

Comment: What is your question? Your generic method [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y8CCCKkWwTjZVp4X)

Comment: `std::forward<Args>(args...)` → `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Comment: You should probably make `args` in `A` into forwarding references too. `template<typename... Args> bool open(int, Args&&... args);` etc.

Comment: `return a.open(int, string, c, args...);` -> `return a.open(i, s, c, args...);` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close since it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: As @Yksisarvinen said, my generic method does work. The only thing is that the compiler does not identify the parameters if I dont explicitly say, ex: `MyStruct{a,b,c}` instead of `{a,b,c}`. For that I'll try to make template specializations for my overloads, but I'm also facing some issues here (I dont know how to explicitly forward each param and call the generic method within the specialization).  It might be best to delete/close this question and I come up later with a better formed one.

Comment: @EduardoLorandi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You could use [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y3KMeMWfv) and add the code that you would like to work (but doesn't).

Comment: please include an example of code you'd like to write but that does not work the way you want in the quesiton

Comment: Now I'm interested in specializing my generic method like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/18d89f6Wz), but I know it is not mandatory to do so given that I can directly call the generic method with "any" parameters. It would only be nice to have the specialization to make it clear which parameters to use.

Comment: If you make it so `B` inherits from `A` then in `B` you would just have `using A::open;`.